# How to fix backtick only working after a delay?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

When I press the <kbd>`</kbd> (backtick) key, I have to hold it down for about a second before it inputs the character. When it starts inputting, it will input a stream (like ```````` ``````` ````````).

How can this be fixed?

---

It is not a dead key. I am using the 'US' layout. Pressing the key twice **does nothing**, I have to press and hold to insert the backtick symbol. This doesn't happen for any other key. 
There are no settings enabled in *Ease of Access → Make the keyboard easier to use*.

**The key works perfectly fine in Ubuntu 13.10** (I'm dual-booting), so it's unlikely to be a hardware issue.

I'm currently using the 'US' keyboard layout, switching to 'United Kingdom' makes the key work normally, however that's not an option as other keys are changed as well. The key also works normally on the login (Welcome) screen.

Comment: Bad contact, dirt? Try wiggling the key and cleaning your keyboard.

Comment: @JanDoggen: The key works fine in Ubuntu on the same computer, it's unlikely that that's the case.

Comment: (Edit. I now saw that you said it's not a dead accent key.) Which version of Windows, and if a laptop, which laptop model?

Comment: @nitro2k01: I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: What happens if you type the key normally and then just sit back and wait for a second? Or if you type the key and then type some other key (e.g., space, period, an alphanumeric)?

Comment: Another idea: As a test, try opening the on-screen keyboard (run, `osk`). Now try pressing that key on the osk with the mouse and see if it behaves the same.

Comment: In the regional settings, what are the following set to? 1) Format 2) Current location under the location tab 3) In "text services and input languages", what is the **language** set to? You can choose the US keyboard layout for certain other languages than English, and this may be related.

Comment: Yet another question. How is the keyboard connected to the computer? USB? PS2? Something else?

Comment: @nitro2k01: RE osk: Clicking the virtual key has the same behaviour (press to insert). RE region settings: Format is English Austrilia; current location is Australia; I can't see a 'text services and languages', but the default input language is English (Australia) - US. RE connection: It's an integrated laptop keyboard.

Comment: @Scott: The second key I pressed is inserted, then, the backtick is ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  (You might want to edit the question to add that information.)  That rules out my theory; I’m out of ideas.

Comment: Which keyboard accessibility settings are you currently using? (see Control Panel > Ease of Access > Ease of Access Center > Make the keyboard easier to use).

Comment: fixed mine: click Start, type "ïntl.cpl", go to "Keyboard and Languages" tab, click "Change Keyboards" button, click "Advanced Key Settings" tab, check the "Hot keys for input languages" box to make sure neither uses the grave accent mark as its trigger.

Comment: I see the same behavior, but only in certain input situations - especially older applications seem to have this issue in editbox style input. In the browser, or in rich HTML editors  I don't see it. It's not a keyboard problem but some sort of software issue related to classic editbox input it appears.

Answer (score 3):

This was happening for me as well, and I fixed it doing the following (was led to this solution by user9999999's suggestion in the op comments.

1. Click Start, type "ïntl.cpl",
2. Go to "Keyboard and Languages" tab,
3. Click "Change Keyboards" button
4. Click "Advanced Key Settings" tab
5. In the "Hot keys for input languages" for the action "Between Input Languages" and click "Change Key Sequence" button below
6. Remove or replace the "grave accent" mark as its trigger with a different one.
7. Click "ok" a couple of times to save and exit the dialog.

Comment: Thank you - this helped me too! First time using a laptop with an EU keyboard and I couldn't for the life of me figure out why this was happening.

Comment: I almost thinking buying a new keyboard for my laptop, what a mess for windows :/ Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The US keyboard doesn't in general behave in such way.
Have you installed some "helpful" keyboard software?

One way to find out is to boot in Safe mode and see if the problem persists.
If it doesn't, then the cause is indeed some installed product.

You could use [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to turn off suspicious startups until you
find the one doing that.

Comment: How would I use X-Mouse button control as a replacement keyboard?

Comment: Not as replacement keyboard, but as a replacement keyboard *software* (if you have one installed, do you?).

Comment: No, I don't have any keyboard software that I'm aware of (should I need one?)

Comment: Not really. Does my suggestion of Safe mode boot give any results?